# What's the difference between these two JS codes in V8?

Tags: javascript, v8

I try to create a codeCache via V8. Use ScriptCompiler::CreateCodeCache function.

```
ScriptCompiler::CachedData* CreateCachedData(Local<String> sourceContent, Local<String> sourceName) {
    ScriptOrigin* scriptOriginPtr = nullptr;
    scriptOriginPtr = new ScriptOrigin(
            String::NewFromTwoByte(isolate_, sourceName, NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked(),
            Integer::New(isolate_, 0), Integer::New(isolate_, 0));
    ScriptCompiler::Source* source = nullptr;
    source = new ScriptCompiler::Source(sourceContent, *scriptOriginPtr);

    Local<Script> script;
    ScriptCompiler::Compile(context_, source, ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions::kEagerCompile).ToLocal(&script);

    ScriptCompiler::CachedData* data = ScriptCompiler::CreateCodeCache(script->GetUnboundScript());

    return data;
}
```

When I use these code, the value of data is nullptr.

```
function A() {
    "use asm"
    function R() {}
    return R
}
```

When I use these code, the value of data isn't nullptr.

```
function A() {
    "use asm"
    function R() {};
    return R
}
```

What's the difference between these two JS codes in V8 or in JS?

Comment: I debug and found that it will return nullptr when CodeSerializer::Serialize

* // TODO(7110): Enable serialization of Asm modules once the AsmWasmData is
 context independent.

`if (script->ContainsAsmModule()) return nullptr;`

Why `ContainsAsmModule()` return false when I add `;` after  `function R() {}`

Comment: Seems to be in contradiction to [“Empty statements (`;`) are always ignored, whether in the top level of a module or inside an asm.js function body.”](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#syntax)

Comment: This was also asked and answered at https://groups.google.com/g/v8-dev/c/nKmM4OHKnU4 .